# How to pass address of BOOL to a method accepting address of VARIANT_BOOL?

Tags: c++, com, com-interop

I have a method which takes a parameter of `VARIANT_BOOL` pointer

```
STDMETHOD(get_Test)(VARIANT_BOOL* result)
```

I also have a `BOOL` test variable I want to pass into that method. It has to be `BOOL` and not `VARIANT_BOOL`.

```
BOOL test;
```

Is there any way pass address of `BOOL` in place of address of `VARIANT_BOOL`? I tried

```
get_Test( &((VARIANT_BOOL)test));
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Are you sure this question is about C#?

Comment: Where does C++ come in?

Comment: This looks like C++, so i've changed title and tag.

Answer (score 4):

Those types have different sizes and use different values for TRUE.  The cast could work if you initialize the value so the upper word is zero.  But just don't and do it like this instead:

```
VARIANT_BOOL temp;
HRESULT hr = get_Test(&temp);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    BOOL test = temp != VARIANT_FALSE;
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is that you should not use a cast for this because `BOOL` is typedefed to `int` and `VARIANT_BOOL` is typedefed to `short` and so they most likely will have different sizes. Declare a `VARIANT_BOOL` variable and pass its address, then interpret the result.

Comment: You may also want to mention that the value `VARIANT_BOOL` uses for true (`VARIANT_TRUE`) is `-1`, rather than `1`.